# Changing sensitivity on a Zowie gaming mouse

Tags: mouse

I'm trying to change the sensitivity of a Zowie gaming mouse.
The slider in the settings doesn't have any effect.

With xinput, the result of

```
xinput list-props 8
```

is

```
Device 'Kingsis Peripherals ZOWIE Gaming mouse':
Device Enabled (155):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (157): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (291):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (292):   0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (293):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (294):   0, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (295):   0, 0, 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button (296): 2
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (297): 2
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (298):    1
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (299):    0
libinput Accel Speed (300): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (301): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (302):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (303):   1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (304):   1, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (305): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (306): 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (276): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (277):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (278):    0, 0
Device Node (279):  "/dev/input/event3"
Device Product ID (280):    6899, 1
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (307):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (308):   1
```

As there is no usual Deceleration property I don't know what to do.

Any ideas, or alternate methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
 xinput --set-prop pointer:"Kingsis Peripherals ZOWIE Gaming mouse"  "libinput Accel Speed" -1
```

to slow it down, you might also try -0.5 etc. Negative to slow down, positive to speed up, range from -1 to 1.

If that doesn't help (or doesn't do what you want), you can also try:

```
xinput --set-prop pointer:"Kingsis Peripherals ZOWIE Gaming mouse" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 10
```

Change the 10 at the end between 0.1 and 20 or so (I actually have no idea what the range is, you can put 100 and it will work, with very small movements of the pointer when zooming all over your desk with the mouse), larger than 1 is slower, negative is inversion of direction.

As you may have guessed, I also have a mouse that has no Deceleration property...